# linear combination of curves to match a single curve with integer constraints

Tags: matlab, linear-programming, least-squares, mixed-integer-programming

I have a set of vectors (curves) which I would like to match to a single curve. The issue isnt only finding a linear combination of the set of curves which will most closely match the single curve (this can be done with least squares Ax = B). I need to be able to add constraints, for example limiting the number of curves used in the fitting to a particular number, or that the curves lie next to each other. These constraints would be found in mixed integer linear programming optimization.

I have started by using lsqlin which allows constraints and have been able to limit the variable to be > 0.0, but in terms of adding further constraints I am at a loss.  Is there a way to add integer constraints to least squares, or alternatively is there a way to solve this with a MILP?

any help in the right direction much appreciated!

**Edit:** Based on the suggestion by ErwinKalvelagen I am attempting to use CPLEX and its quadtratic solvers, however until now I have not managed to get it working. I have created a minimal 'notworking' example and have uploaded  the [data here](https://uploadfiles.io/ztr2s) and code here below. The issue is that matlabs LS solver `lsqlin` is able to solve, however CPLEX `cplexlsqnonneglin` returns **CPLEX Error 5002: %s is not convex** for the same problem.

```
function [ ] = minWorkingLSexample(  )
%MINWORKINGLSEXAMPLE for LS with matlab and CPLEX
%matlab is able to solve the least squares, CPLEX returns error:

% Error using cplexlsqnonneglin
% CPLEX Error  5002: %s is not convex.
%
%
% Error in Backscatter_Transform_excel2_readMut_LINPROG_CPLEX (line 203)
%         cplexlsqnonneglin (C,d);
%  

load('C_n_d_2.mat')

lb = zeros(size(C,2),1);
options = optimoptions('lsqlin','Algorithm','trust-region-reflective');
[fact2,resnorm,residual,exitflag,output] = ...
          lsqlin(C,d,[],[],[],[],lb,[],[],options);


%% CPLEX
ctype = cellstr(repmat('C',1,size(C,2)));
options = cplexoptimset;
options.Display = 'on';

[fact3, resnorm, residual, exitflag, output] = ...
    cplexlsqnonneglin (C,d);

end
```

Comment: What is the problem? Add integer constraints to least-squares? Well... Ax=b is the standardform of (M)IP. Adding aux-vars you can grab the error and process it further. Where is the problem then?

Comment: Probably the easiest is to look at an MIQP solver. This allows a quadratic objective (so Least Squares is easy to implement) and linear and integer restrictions. Solvers likes Cplex and Gurobi include MIQP capabilities.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, I am reading into MIQP, and found CPLEX has a few examples, but the links seem to be broken, Example: cplexlsqmiqcpex.m https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.3.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/Content/Optimization/Documentation/Optimization_Studio/_pubskel/cplex_matlab2429.html is this what you are referring too?

Comment: Yes. You are looking at the Matlab interface to Cplex,(Cplex supports many languages). [Here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/mip_quadratic/03_introMIQCP.html) is a more general page.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Ive tried using cplexlsqmilp, just with same LS I was using before to see if I get the same solution, but I end up with **CPLEX Error  5002: %s is not convex.**. looking further into it I saw that CPLEX implemented a 'CPX_SOLUTIONTARGET_OPTIMALGLOBAL' but I do not believe this applies to the LS solvers.....

Comment: Least squares is convex, so no need to worry about SOLUTIONTARGET. This message indicates your formulation is wrong.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, i must be missing something then because I am trying is to replace **[fact2,resnorm,residual,exitflag,output] = lsqlin(C,d,[],[],[],[],lb,[],[],options);** with a cplex function **[fact2, resnorm, residual, exitflag, output] = cplexlsqnonneglin (C,d);**

Comment: Indeed, this is not a correct translation of the `lsqlin` call. Please read the Cplex documentation more carefully about QP and MIQP models.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen, I am following the documentation from [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.6.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refmatlabcplex/html/cplexlsqnonneglin-m.html) which follows this format. Do you know where more specifically in the documentation I need to look?

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen does it have to do with C and d being **C, Double matrix for objective function. d, Double column vector for objective function** ? they need to be reformatted?

Comment: Sorry, I see now you use different functions, first `cplexlsqmilp` and now `cplexlsqnonneglin`, These are for different problem types (integer vs continuous).

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen yes i am using `cplexlsqnonneglin` with continuous variables, but it is not working

Comment: A much better way of asking questions like "it does not work" is to provide a minimal example allowing to reproduce the problem. Mind reading is really difficult.l

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen apologies, I guess the only way to provide a minimal 'notworking' example is to upload a part of the [data](https://uploadfiles.io/ztr2s) and [code](https://pastebin.com/qB4PAU5s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce the Cplex problem. Here is a workaround. Instead of solving the first model, use a model that is less nonlinear:

[image]

The second model solves fine with Cplex. The problem is somewhat of a tolerance/numeric issue. For the second model we have a much more well-behaved Q matrix (a diagonal). Essentially we moved some of the complexity from the objective into linear constraints.

You should now see something like:

```
Tried aggregator 1 time.
QP Presolve eliminated 1 rows and 1 columns.
Reduced QP has 401 rows, 443 columns, and 17201 nonzeros.
Reduced QP objective Q matrix has 401 nonzeros.
Presolve time = 0.02 sec. (1.21 ticks)
Parallel mode: using up to 8 threads for barrier.
Number of nonzeros in lower triangle of A*A' = 80200
Using Approximate Minimum Degree ordering
Total time for automatic ordering = 0.00 sec. (3.57 ticks)
Summary statistics for Cholesky factor:
  Threads                   = 8
  Rows in Factor            = 401
  Integer space required    = 401
  Total non-zeros in factor = 80601
  Total FP ops to factor    = 21574201
 Itn      Primal Obj        Dual Obj  Prim Inf Upper Inf  Dual Inf          
   0   3.3391791e-01  -3.3391791e-01  9.70e+03  0.00e+00  4.20e+04
   1   9.6533667e+02  -3.0509942e+03  1.21e-12  0.00e+00  1.71e-11
   2   6.4361775e+01  -3.6729243e+02  3.08e-13  0.00e+00  1.71e-11
   3   2.2399862e+01  -6.8231454e+01  1.14e-13  0.00e+00  3.75e-12
   4   6.8012056e+00  -2.0011575e+01  2.45e-13  0.00e+00  1.04e-12
   5   3.3548410e+00  -1.9547176e+00  1.18e-13  0.00e+00  3.55e-13
   6   1.9866256e+00   6.0981384e-01  5.55e-13  0.00e+00  1.86e-13
   7   1.4271894e+00   1.0119284e+00  2.82e-12  0.00e+00  1.15e-13
   8   1.1434804e+00   1.1081026e+00  6.93e-12  0.00e+00  1.09e-13
   9   1.1163905e+00   1.1149752e+00  5.89e-12  0.00e+00  1.14e-13
  10   1.1153877e+00   1.1153509e+00  2.52e-11  0.00e+00  9.71e-14
  11   1.1153611e+00   1.1153602e+00  2.10e-11  0.00e+00  8.69e-14
  12   1.1153604e+00   1.1153604e+00  1.10e-11  0.00e+00  8.96e-14
Barrier time = 0.17 sec. (38.31 ticks)

Total time on 8 threads = 0.17 sec. (38.31 ticks)
QP status(1): optimal
Cplex Time: 0.17sec (det. 38.31 ticks)

Optimal solution found.
Objective :           1.115360
```

See [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2018/01/least-squares-as-qp-convexity-issues.html) for some details.

Update:  In Matlab this becomes:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply, your blog post explains it very well. I try to reformulate however stuck. I use `cplexmiqp ` objective becomes:

 H = diag([[2*ones(1,N)],[zeros(1,N)]]); \\
    f = zeros(1,2*N); \\
    
    % -inf < r < inf \\
    % 0 < x \\
    lb = [-inf*ones(N,1);zeros(N,1)]; \\
    
    %% Equality \\
    % r = C*x - d \\ 
    % r - C*x = -d \\
    
    beq = -d'; \\
    
    [x, fval, exitflag, output] = cplexmiqp (H, f, [], [], Aeq, beq,...
      [], [], [], lb, [], [], [], options);

how should Aeq be written? (sorry that this comment is badly formatted)

Comment: Math lesson added

Comment: thankyou, yes thats what i tried but when I use `Aeq = [diag(ones(N,1)),-C];` however `cplexmiqp` compaints of **Error using cplexmiqp CPLEX encountered arrays with inconsistent lengths.**. the dimensions are H [802x802], f [1x802], lb [802x1], Aeq [401x612], beq [401x1]. Where C is originally [401x211]. Shouldnt Aeq be [802 x rows  of C]?

Comment: Eg H should be 612 x 612

Comment: thanks, I figured out my error, I had wrong though r and x would be the same length. Going over it again I see why they are not!